# Extracting File name from a Foreach of a OpenFileDialog in c#

Tags: c#

Ok I am sure the answer is real easy. But here goes.

```
foreach (String file in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
{
    dm.UploadFile(DMIDENTITY, file, Path.GetExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName), Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog1.FileName));
    // for dev only..  MessageBox.Show(Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog1.FileName));
}
```

It loops through the multiple files with their respective paths fine, but they are also being put into a database as a linked reference. I need JUST the file name not the entire path. Doing it this way however only allows for the first file name to be recognised, and it then puts that in however many times there is a file.

Like I said I am sure its a simple one. But I thought I would propose it to the magical internet wizards of StackOverflow :)

Comment: Note the MessageBox was to test theory that file name is the first one recurring. It is..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looping over all the selected files is correct. However, you're not using the file name of the current loop iteration in all places, but extract extension and file name from the `FileName` property - this is of course wrong.

You need to reference the current loop iteration's file name in all places where you reference the file name:

```
foreach (String file in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
{
    dm.UploadFile(DMIDENTITY, file, Path.GetExtension(file), Path.GetFileName(file));
    // for dev only..  MessageBox.Show(Path.GetFileName(file));
}
```

Comment: Erm - why the downvote? The answer is correct. Boy do I wish downvote-comments were mandatory...

Comment: Wasn't me who downvoted. This did exactly what it said on the tin! Thankyou.